# javascript and dragging in firefox

Tags: javascript, scroll, mootools

I am writing a script to scroll a div container with javascript. Unfortunately it is not working that well in firefox. In firefox the stop-icon appears next to the cursor once I start dragging the knob and then my script is not able to get the mouseup-event.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

http://www.novuspix.de/scroll/

Comment: Nice work until now. What seems to be the problem is that you seem to unbind something when the mouse leaves the scroll area. My suggestion would be to just do binds and unbinds only on mousedown and mouseup.

Comment: You should include the pertinent script and markup, and not make us go look for it. Also, it worked for me in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Better question why reinvent the wheel? Why not use moo more drag? and then utilize the onDrag event for your scrolling calculations? Your main issue right now is that the drag is bubbling up the dom Drag takes care of this for you unless you tell it not too.

Comment: @TimWickstrom.com
You are right, that would be a faster way to do it.

Comment: @FishBasketGordo 
It failed only the second time in firefox. I guess because it was not able the get the mouseleave event.

Comment: @felix Glad that you got your problem fixed. For posterity's sake, it would still be good if you updated your question with your original markup and scripts and what you did to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that `mousemove` event attached to `document` or `window` and not to the `.knob` element.

Answer (score -1):

For those looking for a fix to a stop icon blocking the mouseup event (as I was when I found this post) I asked the question too, and finally found the answer myself which is here : [**SOLVED** Click and drag on links in Firefox are blocking mouseup events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53227879/solved-click-and-drag-on-links-in-firefox-are-blocking-mouseup-events)

here is the JS code, everything is more detail on the question

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
links.forEach(element => {element.addEventListener('mousedown',function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault();
})
})
```

Comment: this should better be a comment instead of an answer or possible duplicate

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21370689)

Comment: I need 50 reputation to comment a question that's why, however sorry about it just wanted to help :/

Comment: Seriously ? discard me for trying to help ? I even provided the code and did the modification in a minute... not fair... not fair