# Click and drag on links in Firefox are blocking mouseup events

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, mouseevent

I want to achieve an horizontal click and dragg website, it works perfectly in Chrome but not in Firefox.

**My problem :** Click and dragg on links in Firefox is making the stop-icon appears next to the cursor and then blocking `mouseup` event.

**What I know :** The problem is only appearing on links and I found this post ([javascript and dragging in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320505/javascript-and-dragging-in-firefox)) that is suggesting to use `addEventListener` on the `document`, but it didn't fix it.

**Old code below** (to see the updated one go on codepen)

```
const slider = document.querySelector('.items');
let isDown = false;
let startX;
let scrollLeft;

document.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  isDown = true;
  slider.classList.add('active');
  startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
});
document.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  isDown = false;
  slider.classList.remove('active');
});
document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  isDown = false;
  slider.classList.remove('active');
});
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if(!isDown) return;
  e.preventDefault();
  const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  const walk = (x - startX) * 3; //scroll-fast
  slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk;
  console.log(walk);
});
```

HTML

```
    <div class="grid-container">

  <main class="grid-item main">
    <div class="items">
      <a class="item item1" href="#"></a>
      <a class="item item2" href="#"></a>
      <a class="item item3"></a>
      <a class="item item4"></a>
      <div class="item item5"></div>
      <div class="item item6"></div>
      <div class="item item7"></div>
      <div class="item item8"></div>
      <div class="item item9"></div>
      <div class="item item10"></div>
    </div>
    <p>Click & Drag <i>powered by Javascript</i></p>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: don't ask/answer in the question .. keep the question then add an answer to it if you find a solution

Comment: Yeah you right it's done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION : To fix the problem you can do

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
links.forEach(element => {element.addEventListener('mousedown',function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault();
})
})
```

Here is the link :https://codepen.io/greg_o/pen/jQrMON